# What's the meaning of {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} exactly?

Tags: windows

I want to know what's the meaning of {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} exactly?

For example, if I create a folder and rename this folder to `.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`, I can see an empty folder without any change in directory.

If I create a folder and rename this folder to `x.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`, I can see an empty folder with a little change in directory. This change: `{Current}\x`

If I create a folder and rename this folder to `..{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`, I can see an empty folder with a little changes in directory. This change: `{Current}\.`

If I create a folder and rename this folder to `con.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}`, I can see an error.

Answer (score 2):

I've googled:

> {21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D} guid

and apparently it's the GUID of the Control Panel.

Some sources from top 10 results:

- https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_sterowania
- https://www.dbmauro.com/knowledgebase/shortcut-of-class-id-clsid-guidgobally-unique-identifier/
- https://www.tenforums.com/customization/152314-shell-destinations.html
- https://winaero.com/clsid-guid-shell-list-windows-10/
- https://www.programmersought.com/article/821034567/